# mfpic graphics show just blank boxex

Tags: graphics

I am really new to LaTeX and this might be a stupid question but I spent hours to figure out how to make the actual figure showing up in TeXnicCenter. Would you please help me?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[metapost,mplabels]{mfpic}
\opengraphsfile{mypics}
\begin{document}
Hyperbolic metric disks:

\begin{mfpic}[72]{-1}{1}{-1}{1}
  \setmfpair{Z}{(dir 45)/3}
  \setmfpair{W}{Moebius (Z)(.5*dir -45)}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.94)]\circle{(0,0),1}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.87)]\pshcircle{Z,4/5}
  \gfill[gray(.80)]\pshcircle{Z,1/2}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.73)]\pshcircle{W,1/2}
  \draw\pshcircle{Z,1/2}
  \tlpointsep{3bp}
  \point{Z,W,(0,0)}
  \tlabel[br]{Z}{$z$}
  \tlabel[tl]{W}{$w$}
  \tlabel[tr]{(0,0)}{$0$}
\end{mfpic}

Hyperbolic geodesics:

\begin{mfpic}[72]{-1}{1}{-1}{1}
  \circle{(0,0),1}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.88)]
    \lclosed
    \connect
      \hypergeodesic{.999*dir 0, .999*dir 120}
      \hypergeodesic{.999*dir 120, .999*dir 240}
      \hypergeodesic{.999*dir 240, .999*dir 0}
    \endconnect
  \mfpfor{K=6,12,24,48}
    \mfpfor{J=0 upto K-1}
      \rotatepath{(0,0),J*(360/K)}\hypergeodesic{.999*dir 0, .999*dir (360/K)}
    \endmfpfor
  \endmfpfor
\end{mfpic}

\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

[image: Blank image figure box]

Comment: Did you run Metapost on `mypics.mp`?

Comment: Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Sorry would you please tell me how to run mypics.mp?

Comment: Open a command window (or how it's called in Windows) and type `mpost mypics` ensuring the current directory is where your LaTeX file resides. Maybe there are easier ways with TeXnicCenter, but I really know nothing about the program.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run `mpost` on the `mypics.mp` file. How, precisely, depends on your OS and TeX distribution.

However, on a fairly recent TeX distribution, you can make TeX do it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[metapost,mplabels]{mfpic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mfp@closegraphsfile}
  {\closeout\mfp@out}
  {\closeout\mfp@out\ShellEscape{r-mpost \mfp@filename}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\opengraphsfile{mypics}
\begin{document}
Hyperbolic metric disks:

\begin{mfpic}[72]{-1}{1}{-1}{1}
  \setmfpair{Z}{(dir 45)/3}
  \setmfpair{W}{Moebius (Z)(.5*dir -45)}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.94)]\circle{(0,0),1}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.87)]\pshcircle{Z,4/5}
  \gfill[gray(.80)]\pshcircle{Z,1/2}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.73)]\pshcircle{W,1/2}
  \draw\pshcircle{Z,1/2}
  \tlpointsep{3bp}
  \point{Z,W,(0,0)}
  \tlabel[br]{Z}{$z$}
  \tlabel[tl]{W}{$w$}
  \tlabel[tr]{(0,0)}{$0$}
\end{mfpic}

Hyperbolic geodesics:

\begin{mfpic}[72]{-1}{1}{-1}{1}
  \circle{(0,0),1}
  \draw\gfill[gray(.88)]
    \lclosed
    \connect
      \hypergeodesic{.999*dir 0, .999*dir 120}
      \hypergeodesic{.999*dir 120, .999*dir 240}
      \hypergeodesic{.999*dir 240, .999*dir 0}
    \endconnect
  \mfpfor{K=6,12,24,48}
    \mfpfor{J=0 upto K-1}
      \rotatepath{(0,0),J*(360/K)}\hypergeodesic{.999*dir 0, .999*dir (360/K)}
    \endmfpfor
  \endmfpfor
\end{mfpic}

\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

Thus the `\closegraphsfile` command will process the produced `.mp` file and the pictures will be loaded at the next run.

The code calls `r-mpost`, which is sufficient for the purpose and runs also with the restricted (safer) shell-escape, whereas `mpost` requires the unrestricted (less safe) shell-escape.

[image]