# Blank Boxes with mfpic in exam class

Tags: graphics, compiling, metapost, compilation-error

I'm working on a document that uses `mfpic`and would like to compile without having to do `mpost` every time.

I tried to use the code given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186814/mfpic-graphics-show-just-blank-boxex), but have been unsuccessful.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
\title{College Algebra \\ Relations Worksheet}
\date{Feb 17, 2019}
\opengraphsfile{RelationsQuiz}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mfp@closegraphsfile}
  {\global}
  {\immediate\write18{mpost \mfp@filename}\global}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Text here
\begin{mfpic}[15]{-5}{5}{-2}{5}
\point[4pt]{(-4, 3), (-3, 2), (-3, 4), (0, -1), (2, 3), (4, 0)}
\axes
\tlabel[cc](5,-0.5){$x$}
\tlabel[cc](0.5,5){$y$}
\xmarks{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\ymarks{-1,1,2,3,4}
\tlpointsep{5pt}
\scriptsize
\axislabels {x}{{$-4 \hspace{7pt}$} -4, {$-3 \hspace{7pt}$} -3, {$-2 \hspace{7pt}$} -2, {$-1 \hspace{7pt}$} -1, {$1$} 1, {$2$} 2, {$3$} 3, {$4$} 4}
\axislabels {y}{{$-1$} -1, {$1$} 1, {$2$} 2, {$3$} 3, {$4$} 4}
\end{mfpic}
\question \begin{mfpic}[15]{-4}{4}{-4}{4}

\hatchcolor[gray]{.7}
\lhatch \rect{(2,-4), (-3.75,1)}
\axes
\arrow \dashed \polyline{(2,1), (2,-4)}
\arrow \polyline{(2,1), (-4,1)}
\gclear \circle{(2,1),0.1}
\circle{(2,1),0.1}
\tlabel[cc](4,-0.5){$x$}
\tlabel[cc](0.5,4){$y$}
\xmarks{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\ymarks{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\tlpointsep{5pt}
\scriptsize
\axislabels {x}{{$-3 \hspace{7pt}$} -3,{$-2 \hspace{7pt}$} -2,{$-1 \hspace{7pt}$} -1,{$1$} 1,{$2$} 2,{$3$} 3}
\axislabels {y}{ {$-3$} -3,{$-2$} -2, {$-1$} -1, {$1$} 1, {$2$} 2, {$3$} 3}
\normalsize
\end{mfpic} 
\end{questions}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need two runs of LaTeX with the `-shell-escape` option active.

Comment: @egreg I’m using LaTeXmk. Shouldn’t that already be taken care of

Comment: No idea, sorry. For a short period, `mpost` had been in the “safe list” for being run even without shell-escape active. It seems that a “restricted version” of `mpost` will be available with TL 2019. Anyway, look for `shell-escape` in the documentation of `latexmk`. It should also be possible to make it run metapost by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the call to `mpost` into one to `r-mpost`, which is a restricted version of `mpost` that's allowed to run with the restricted shell-escape and is sufficient for `mfpic`.

I'd like, nowadays to do it without resorting to `\patchcmd`, but unfortunately `mfpic` provides no sensible hook for this purpose.
Using `shellesc` is recommended over `\immediate\write18`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{College Algebra \\ Relations Worksheet}
\date{Feb 17, 2019}

\opengraphsfile{\jobname-mfpic}% just not to clobber my files

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mfp@closegraphsfile}
  {\immediate\closeout\mfp@out}
  {\immediate\closeout\mfp@out\ShellEscape{r-mpost \mfp@filename}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Text here
\begin{mfpic}[15]{-5}{5}{-2}{5}
\point[4pt]{(-4, 3), (-3, 2), (-3, 4), (0, -1), (2, 3), (4, 0)}
\axes
\tlabel[cc](5,-0.5){$x$}
\tlabel[cc](0.5,5){$y$}
\xmarks{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\ymarks{-1,1,2,3,4}
\tlpointsep{5pt}
\scriptsize
\axislabels {x}{{$-4 \hspace{7pt}$} -4, {$-3 \hspace{7pt}$} -3, {$-2 \hspace{7pt}$} -2,
  {$-1 \hspace{7pt}$} -1, {$1$} 1, {$2$} 2, {$3$} 3, {$4$} 4}
\axislabels {y}{{$-1$} -1, {$1$} 1, {$2$} 2, {$3$} 3, {$4$} 4}
\end{mfpic}
\question \begin{mfpic}[15]{-4}{4}{-4}{4}

\hatchcolor[gray]{.7}
\lhatch \rect{(2,-4), (-3.75,1)}
\axes
\arrow \dashed \polyline{(2,1), (2,-4)}
\arrow \polyline{(2,1), (-4,1)}
\gclear \circle{(2,1),0.1}
\circle{(2,1),0.1}
\tlabel[cc](4,-0.5){$x$}
\tlabel[cc](0.5,4){$y$}
\xmarks{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\ymarks{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\tlpointsep{5pt}
\scriptsize
\axislabels {x}{{$-3 \hspace{7pt}$} -3,{$-2 \hspace{7pt}$} -2,
  {$-1 \hspace{7pt}$} -1,{$1$} 1,{$2$} 2,{$3$} 3}
\axislabels {y}{ {$-3$} -3,{$-2$} -2, {$-1$} -1, {$1$} 1, {$2$} 2, {$3$} 3}
\normalsize
\end{mfpic} 
\end{questions}

\closegraphsfile

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, to get the triple compilation (latex+mpost+latex) in one stroke, I use the following shell script on my Mac OS X system, through the command line as well as through the TeXShop graphic interface (via the `Engines` feature, for those who use TeXShop). This kind of script should work on any Unix system. It certainly needs to be adapted on others.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set filename = "$1"
set mpname = "${filename:r}.mp"

pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 "$filename"
mpost "$mpname"
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 "$filename"
```